# Chinese character inputs in scrapy xpath

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a Chinese language website using Scrapy in Python 2.

I want all the elements that contain the character '下'. First I tried this in the scrapy shell:

```
x = response.xpath('\\*[contains(.,'下')]').extract()
```

So then it old me to only use unicode or ASCII, so I tried these:

```
x = response.xpath('\\*[contains(.,'\u4e0b')]').extract()
x = response.xpath('\\*[contains(.,u'\u430b')]').extract()
x = response.xpath(u'\\*[contains(.,'\u430b')]').extract()
```

Those mostly returned an "unexpected character after line continuation..." error.

Then I tried:

```
y = '下'.decode('utf-8')    
x = response.xpath('\\*[contains(.,y)]').extract()
```

That didn't throw up any errors but it returned every element on the website.

I'm at my wit's end here...what am I doing wrong? Thanks! I'm pretty new at this so please bear with me...

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know what kind of html you are dealing with i created minimal sample that works.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = '<html><body><div><h1>下</h1></div></body></html>'
special_char = '下'
x = Selector(text=body).xpath(u"//h1[contains(.,'{0}')]".format(special_char)).extract() 
print(x[0])
```

gives

```
<h1>下</h1>
```